# Bootstrap doesn't show Tooltips jQuery error

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, tooltip, cdn

Hello stack overflow comunity,

yes - this is not a new topic but i only found old threads regarding bootstrap tooltips with old js and no popper.js, ..

I try to use bootstraps tooltip but it does not work. Are there any changes in the current version? 
For testing i have created a simple file just with the example buttons, css and all js included.

The Tooltips does not work :-/

Here is my example page:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    <title>Bootstrap Tests</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
      $(function() {
        $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
      });
    </script>

    <button
      type="button"
      class="btn btn-secondary"
      data-toggle="tooltip"
      data-placement="top"
      title="Tooltip on top"
    >
      Tooltip on top
    </button>
    <button
      type="button"
      class="btn btn-secondary"
      data-toggle="tooltip"
      data-placement="right"
      title="Tooltip on right"
    >
      Tooltip on right
    </button>
    <button
      type="button"
      class="btn btn-secondary"
      data-toggle="tooltip"
      data-placement="bottom"
      title="Tooltip on bottom"
    >
      Tooltip on bottom
    </button>
    <button
      type="button"
      class="btn btn-secondary"
      data-toggle="tooltip"
      data-placement="left"
      title="Tooltip on left"
    >
      Tooltip on left
    </button>

    <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script
      src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The console shows the error $ not defined - Win10/ Firefox 74

Answer (score 0):

Check your browser - are all scripts loaded -see development console
Are any extensions blocking the behaviour - scripts prohibited etc.
On Firefox 74.0 (64-Bit) Windows as well Mac Sierra it works like expected apart from that the buttons are at the top so the tooltip for top is shown below -but thats imho ok.
EDIT after OP repley:
$ is not defined means for some reason jQuery is not loaded correctly. 
Try loading the libs from your local HDD, not from the CDN.
Perhaps your virus checker blocks loading correctly or an extension blocks sxript execution. 
The code is working as expected on my machines

Comment: hmm I am using Firefox 74.0 on da 64bit Windows 10 Workstation. The only Error I see in the Console is 

ReferenceError: $ is not defined

But i think the javascript is correct:
<script>
      $(function() {
        $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
      });
    </script>

Comment: $ is not defined means for some reason jQuery is not loaded correctly. Try loading the libs from your local HDD, not from the CDN.(Perhaps your virus checker blocks loading correctly)- As I wrote your code workson my machines so its connection or loading the js files!

Comment: maybe it's something with xampp... if I upload this example Page to my webserver i get many content security errors. 

Thank you for your help - now I know where to search the problem :-)